# Slideshow with (intentional) overlapping

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have this slideshow:

```
<div id="leftBtn">Left</div>
<div id="rightBtn">Right</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="slideshowContainer">
        <div id="slide_1" class="slide"></div>
        <div id="slide_2" class="slide"></div>
        <div id="slide_3" class="slide"></div>
        <div id="slide_4" class="slide"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

... with a sliding left effect. It works great (all credits to jimjimmy1995 for the code). What I want is for each slide to overlapp the previous one when clicking the right button and the reverse when clicking the left button. Also tweaking the opacity would be nice.
Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkyZx/).
Thank you in advance.

Pedro

Comment: This is basically a job assignment.

Comment: Yes, I know it's something to do with the z-index, but, how do I do that whith this code (check fiddle)?

Comment: I'm not a jQuery savvy, I would really appreciate your help guys.